# Does this optimization problem have a closed form solution?

Tags: optimization, closed-form, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

Consider the following optimization problem

$$\min \qquad         \omega^H \omega  \\ 
 \text{s. t.} \quad \omega^H A \omega \geq a,  \\
\quad \quad \omega^H B \omega \geq b $$

where $A$ and $B$ are $m \times m$ postive semi-definite matrices, $\omega$ is $m \times 1$ vector and $a$ and $b$ are scalars. Does this optimization problem have a closed form solution? If so, please give me link or explanation.

I look forward to your priceless answer. Thank you!

ps)edit: semi-definite matrices -> positive semi-definite matrices

Comment: Define "semi-definite".

Comment: This is not, in fact, convex. (@RodrigodeAzevedo I assume he means positive semidefinite.)